# Dynamic memory allocation vs std::vector for class private member C++

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory

While learning c++ I usually (very often) encounter the following advice: "Avoid dynamic memory allocation as **much as you can**; use std::vectors instead as they handle this for you".

So my question is: When do I **have to** use dynamic memory allocation? All the exercises I have done (I am just a beginner) are much easier using `std::vector`; nevertheless my lecturer forces us to use dynamic memory for simple classes (like matrices, geometric vectors, etc.) and `delete[]` in the destructor.

The only advantage I have found so far for `new;delete[];` (or at least what I tell my self in order to feel that it is worth using dynamic memory) is using move copy and move assignment.

Comment: *"The only advantage I have found so far..."* Are you talking about `std::vector` or `new`/`delete`?

Comment: std::vector does dynamic memory allocation.  The point is that you shouldn't do it directly (or at least do it in a wrapper) rather than not doing it at all

Comment: You have to use dynamic memory allocation whenever your lecturer tells you to. Presumably, the goal is to learn how to manage dynamic memory allocation, or, perhaps, to learn why you shouldn't do it on your own.

Comment: *The only advantage I have found so far for new;delete[]; (or at least what I tell my self in order to feel that it is worth using dynamic memory) is using move copy and move assignment.* Hate to burst your bubble but with `new`/`delete` you have to write your own constructors, which is work.  With a `std::vector` you don't have to write anything.  You get a copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment operators, and a destructor provided for you by the compiler, which is much less work.

Comment: The very best code is the code you don't have to write

Comment: @NathanOliver Rubbish.  Using std::vector or not won't change which functions the compiler will generate for you.

Comment: @James But it will change what correct constructors you get.  The defaults aren't acceptable if you're using `new`/`delete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are situations where you *may* need to implement a custom container (because neither `std::vector` nor any of the other standard library containers fit your purpose), and in those cases it *may* make sense to do the memory management manually.

However, unless you are providing the low-level core components in some industrial grade code base and have very specific goals, doing manual memory management is probably still not necessary here either.

I agree with the strict rules of your lecturer insofar that it pays to understand what happens behind the scenes. You rarely, if ever, should *have to* use manual memory management, but it helps to understand how `std::unique_ptr`/`std::vector` (*have to*) do it for you in order to understand why C++ was built the way it is. Teaching C++ in a way that is useful in the real world would eventually allow/force you to use standard library containers though, because there is (as you correctly noticed) essentially no reason to ever write a `delete`.

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector` also does dynamic memory allocation behind the scenes (by using the `new` operator).
Copy and move assignment are also defined for `std::vector`, as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), so there is no speed gained if you do it by hand.

Probably your question refers to when should you *manually* allocate memory (by explicitly using `new` and `delete`), as opposed to relying on another class (such as vector) to do it for you.

The "Modern C++" answer to this question is to *never* do memory management by hand.
If an `std::vector` does the job, then use that instead. If you need to allocate a single item, then use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Not quite, my nitpick is that `std::vector` uses an [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) to allocate and initialize the memory. This is an important distinction because allocators can be customized per instance `operator new` in this case would be global.

Comment: "to never do memory management by hand" - That is an even stronger statement than "avoid it as much as you can". Are you suggesting that it is possible to *never need*  `new;delete[]`?

Comment: @Mgetz `std::vector<T>` uses `std::allocator<T>` which uses `operator new`, which is good default behaviour.

Comment: @DanielDuque Yes. Not only possible but likely.

Comment: @Caleth by default yes, but that is implementation defined. It is not required to use `operator new`

Comment: @Mgetz "Remarks: the storage is obtained by calling ​`::​operator new`, but it is unspecified when or how often this function is called." [`[allocator.members/3]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.members#3)

Comment: @Caleth and your point is? `std::vector` still uses an allocator.

Comment: @Mgetz my point is that `std::vector<T>` uses `new`, *via* it's allocator, and only at the point where you do care do you *have to care* there is an allocator.

Comment: @Caleth I think you missed my point then. Which was that `std::vector` is in no way hard tied to `operator new` and to state that is incorrect.

Comment: `std::vector` only names a type post C++17, at which point the deduction guide infers `std::allocator`, so in a real sense, *it is*

Comment: @Mgetz For any default use it will call `new`: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/default.allocator#allocator.members-3  The Answer's comment might not be 100% accurate but it will cover the majority of cases.

Comment: @NathanOliver @caleth you both completely missed what I was getting at. The fact it will use `operator new` by default is irrelevant pedantry. The point is that `std::vector` is not hard tied to `operator new`. I'm not sure what I'm failing to communicate here. This will be my last post as I'm getting quite frustrated at how irrelevant this has gotten. My post was a nitpick, I don't consider the respondent's post fundamentally flawed for the reasons you've pointed out. I was just supplying supplemental information.

Answer (score 1):

The lecturer most likely forces you so you get an idea of how things work under the hood. The std::vector class as you mentioned handles all the dynamic memory management for you, such that you do not need to write all the code to handle this yourself. It is easy, especially as a beginner to mess up while handling dynamic memory and create a leak/forget to deallocate something.

A vector is however not the solution for every problem, and you may find cases where it does not fit all your critera - and in those cases it could be better to implement your own data structure.

Comment: *"lecturer most likely forces you so you get an idea of how things work under the hood"* It's not a bad thing by itself, but most of the time they don't even bother to tell studends about the rule of three. D:

Comment: Could you provide a basic example for when a vector won't fit all my criteria and it would be better to directly dynamic allocate memory?

Comment: @DanielDuque I was here pointing towards using maps, trees or other structures that may be more efficient for certain operations.

For a dynamic array I would always use a vector over manual dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @DanielDuque cases requiring extremely strict allignment standards for extremely high performance code.

Comment: "and in those cases it could be better to use a different data structure, in which case look at the other `std` containers, `boost` containers, and only if none of those fit your needs implement your own data structure"